# Complex Query using Sitecore 8 content search API

Tags: c#, linq, sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to write a Linq to iterate through list of ID's using sitecore content search API but it throws this exception

> Invalid Method Call Argument Type: Field - FieldNode - Field: supplier_categories_sm - DCP.Common.Models.Shared.CategoryItem[]. Only constant arguments is supported.

```
   //The search item class
 public class EventSupplierItem : BaseSearchItem
 {
    [IndexField("supplier_categories_sm")]
    public CategoryItem[] SupplierCategories { get; set; } //maped to multilist
 }
 //I have wrote custom converter to map the multilist to that item
 public class CategoryItem
{
    [SitecoreId]
    [IndexField("_group")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldIDValueConverter))]
    public virtual ID Id { set; get; }

    [IndexField("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The code to create the filter predicate to get results:

```
  var EventCategoryID = new ID(EventSupplierFilters.SupplierCategory);
                    FilterOR = FilterOR.Or(x => x.SupplierCategories.Select(a => a.Id).Contains(EventCategoryID));
                    filter = filter.And(FilterOR.Predicate);
 results = queryable.Filter(filter.Predicate);
 executedResults = results.ToList();
```

I have also tried using the `.Any` instead of `.Select` but still throws the same exception as Sitecore content search linq doesn't support `Any` or `Select` in the expression. 
Does anyone know what's the best way to deal with this issue ?

Comment: Possibly due to the Id property being virtual, can you try without it being virtual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore LINQ might not be able to resolve your complex query, Try the following, it will return the expected results:

```cs
var normalizedID = Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.IdHelper.NormalizeGuid(EventSupplierFilters.SupplierCategory,true);
FilterOR = FilterOR.Or(x => x["supplier_categories_sm"].Contains(normalizedID));
filter = filter.And(FilterOR.Predicate);
results = queryable.Filter(filter.Predicate);
executedResults = results.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Fortis source code there is an example of how to do this. There are 2 extension methods, `.ContainsAnd` and `.ContainsOr` that take a list of Id's to compare against another field.

Here is the source: https://github.com/Fortis-Collection/fortis/blob/master/Fortis/Search/SearchExtensions.cs

You can probably customize that to your needs.

In use we call:

```
var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<IItemWrapper>().ContainsOr(x => x.FieldName, arrayValues);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a great help! the source is different now! but the same repository.
https://github.com/Fortis-Collection/fortis/blob/518f40549f295a07f7e063d4dfae5923e9f88736/src/Fortis/Search/SearchExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause of the problem is that these expressions need to be resolved to [Lucene queries](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) which is quite restricted compared with what you'd expect to work. The way I think of it is that everything being turned into the query needs to be resolved into a formatted string query - [more information on that is explained here](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2013/05/sitecore-7-search-provider-part-8-converting-linq-expressions.aspx).

The simplest thing to do would probably be to use single 'Where' queries to compare one thing at a time, and then when you need the complicated logic convert it to a List before trying to run complicated IEnumerable queries against it.

Alternatively you can dig in and try understand how constant expressions work in LINQ - it's not something I'm really familiar with though.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a similar problem and went down the route of using my own Expression trees.

Here's an example of doing a `Contains` match on a list of Ids that are retrieved from the search index.

```
   public static Expression<Func<CustomSearchResultItem, bool>> MatchOnMultipleValues(IEnumerable<string> arrayOfIds, string parameter)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<CustomSearchResultItem>();
        foreach (var id in arrayOfIds)
        {
            // create dynamic expression tree for filter for Enumerable properties (multivalued)
            Expression constant = Expression.Constant(id);
            ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CustomSearchResultItem), "s");
            Expression property = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, parameter);

            // Call contains method on IEnumerable
            var callExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }, property, constant);
            predicate = predicate.Or(Expression.Lambda<Func<CustomSearchResultItem, Boolean>>(callExpression, parameterExpression));
        }
        return predicate;
    }

  query = query.Where(ExpressionMatches.MatchOnMultipleValues(arrayIds, Id));
```

`CustomSearchResultItem` is my own POCO class for handling the search results which will function in the same way as your `EventSupplierItem` class. The `matchonmultiplevalues` method is doing a contains on an array of strings but you could adapt this to use an array of `CategoryItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you need to get the ids and then build your query with them rather than doing a select statement in the filter or.  I have had a lot of trouble with this when building some complex predicate expressions for search :)